# frequency of occurence

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have a tab-delimited text file, that is around 3K lines long.

I want to calculate frequency of data appearing in it, in 10,000 ranges.

Input.txt

```
Price  
500    
1500   
10001   
15000  
17000  
25000  
33000  
39000  
:
:
8000000
```

Output.txt

```
Pricerange      pricerangecount  
0-10000          2               
10000-20000      3               
20000-30000      1               
30000-40000      2 
:
:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Pricerange\tpricerangecount"}
     NR>1 {cur=int($0/10000); A[cur]+=1; if (cur>m) m=cur; }
     END {for(i=0;i<=m;i++) printf("%d-%d:\t%d\n",i*10000, (i+1)*10000, A[i])}'
```

Comment: Small cosmetical change suggested: awk 'BEGIN{print "Pricerange\tpricerangecount"} {cur=int($0/10000); A[cur]+=1; if (cur>m) m=cur; } END {for(i=0;i<=m;i++) printf("%d-%d:\t%d\n",i*10000, (i+1)*10000, A[i])}'

Comment: @tink, right and we should skip first line in input too. But then no longer comfortably a one-liner. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I generally use `gsl-histogram` from the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) package. As one-liner as it gets in your case (without pretty-printing, the previous solutions are all right, and I have upvoted them):

```
  tail -n+2 Input.txt | gsl-histogram 0 40000 4
```

Comment: Nice. To skip the header it should be `tail -n+2`.

Answer (score 3):

Perl:

```
perl -ne'$h{int$_/10000}++;END{printf"%d0000-%d0000  %d\n",$_,$_+1,$h{$_}for sort{$a<=>$b}keys%h}'
```

expanded:

```
while(<>) { #read each line (-n)
  $h{int $_/10000}++; #count buckets
}
for (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %h) { #sort numerically
  printf "%d0000-%d0000  %d\n", $_, $_+1, $h{$_};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a coreutils and dc alternative:

```
<Input.txt tail -n +2 | while read; do <<< "$REPLY 10000 /p" | dc; done | sort -n | uniq -c \
   | while read cnt rng; do 
       printf "%-15s %-15s\n" \
         $(<<< "$rng 10000 *p" | dc)-$(<<< "$rng 1 + 10000 *p" | dc) $cnt
     done > Output.txt
```

Output.txt:

```
0-10000         2
10000-20000     3
20000-30000     1
30000-40000     2
```

Comment: there is no need to sort ; here a solution with bash `shopt -s extglob; N=10000; while read n;do [[ $n = *(0-9) ]]&&((a[n/N]++));done; for i in ${!a[*]};do echo $((i*N))-$(((i+1)*N-1)) $((a[i]));done`

Comment: `uniq` is counting occurrences so sorting is needed. You should post your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although bash is not a good solution, following a comment, here another solution

```
N=10000
while read n;do [[ $n =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]]&&((a[n/N]++));done
for i in ${!a[*]};do echo $((i*N))-$(((i+1)*N-1)) $((a[i]));done
```

it will be faster on small files because there isn't the overhead of spawning a new process but less efficient on large files.